SwiftUI Mapkit: How can I select Mapkit-Items AND custom Markers
I have a map with Apples pre-defined ityour textems like "beaches". AND I have set some own markers (which will show "my beaches").
The markers are set as follows:
private let myMarkers: [(id: Int, name: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)] = [
            (1, "Apple Developer Academy", CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.836639, longitude: 14.306602)),
            (2, "Restaurant", CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.834890, longitude: 14.304400)),
            (3, "Coffee Bar", CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.836901, longitude: 14.302562)),
            (4, "Beach", CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 54.41621, longitude: 10.18242))
                        
        ]

When I initialize the map, I define the "position" and the "selection" (as follows).
Now:
If I only habe Apple-MapItems, I declare:
@State private var mySelectedAppleItem: MKMapItem?
and I initialize:
Map(position: $position, selection: $mySelected**AppleItem**) {//Type: MKMapItem
AND:
If I only habe My-Map-"Items" (which are, if I see it correctly, not MKMapItems, but "only" marked locations, I declare:
@State private var mySelectedTag: Int?
and I initialize:
Map(position: $position, selection: $mySelected**Tag**) {//Type: Int
So:
When I choose the Apple-Selection (selection: $mySelectedAppleItem), I can easily select the Apple-Items, but my own Markers, although marked with a tag, are NOT selectable. And when I choose My-Selection (selection: $mySelectedTag), I can only select my tagged Markers
Here is my question: Is there a way that I can select BOTH? For example via an extension of MapItem (can I declare my "items" as "Mapkit-Item"?)?
Thanks a lot!
I searched a lot, but couldn't find any article on this.

Are you using the pre-iOS 17 MapKit? Do you need to support iOS 16?

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
Typically your mySelected type must match the tag. Instead of using the objects for tags/selection, try using their identifier.

Try this approach, using a common identifier type for MKMapItem and myMarkers.
For example,
give your MKMapItem(rawValue: "item-1") also give your myMarkers tuples
[(identifier: "myMarker-1", ...., instead of [(id: Int, ....
Then use,
 @State private var selectedTag: String?   // both for MKMapItem and myMarkers

.tag(item.identifier)

This has the selectedTag and the .tags of the same type, to make the selection possible.

did my answer not work for you?
